# Nerdbank.GitVersioning with same config gives different results

Tags: versioning

I've just setup Nerdbank.GitVersionning in my project and I have the same setup as Dapper

Here is my version.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/master/src/NerdBank.GitVersioning/version.schema.json",
  "version": "0.1.0-alpha.{height}",
  "assemblyVersion": "0.1.0.0",
  "publicReleaseRefSpec": [
    "^refs/heads/master$",
    "^refs/tags/v\\d+\\.\\d+"
  ],
  "nugetPackageVersion": {
    "semVer": 2
  },
  "cloudBuild": {
    "buildNumber": {
      "enabled": true,
      "setVersionVariables": true
    }
  }
}
```

If I do nbgv get-version:

```
Version:                      0.1.0.1
AssemblyVersion:              0.1.0.0
AssemblyInformationalVersion: 0.1.0-alpha.1+021de4e5ee
NuGet package Version:        0.1.0-alpha.1
NPM package Version:          0.1.0-alpha.1
```

Here is Dapper's version.json

```
{
  "version": "1.50.8-alpha.{height}",
  "assemblyVersion": "1.50.0.0",
  "publicReleaseRefSpec": [
    "^refs/heads/master$",
    "^refs/tags/v\\d+\\.\\d+"
  ],
  "nugetPackageVersion": {
    "semVer": 2
  },
  "cloudBuild": {
    "buildNumber": {
      "enabled": true,
      "setVersionVariables": true
    }
  }
}
```

If I do nbgv get-version:

```
Version:                      1.50.8.23
AssemblyVersion:              1.50.0.0
AssemblyInformationalVersion: 1.50.8-alpha.23+e7020b2bde
NuGet package Version:        1.50.8-alpha.23.e7020b2bde
NPM package Version:          1.50.8-alpha.23.e7020b2bde
```

Any idea on why there is a difference on Nuget & NPM package version?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are in the master branch in your repo, and not in master in the Dapper repo. That's why the git commit ids are being dropped from the NuGet / NPM package version strings. According to https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/blob/master/doc/versionJson.md:

> The `publicReleaseRefSpec` field causes builds out of certain branches or tags to automatically drop the -gabc123 git commit ID suffix from the version, making it convenient to build releases out of these refs with a friendly version number that assumes linear versioning.